# How to make Magnolia CMS work with Phonegap

Tags: html, cordova, render, magnolia

So i am trying to make some pages in magnolia so they work in phoneGap, phoneGap is a wrapper that wraps HTML5/CSS/JavaScript and deploys them as a mobile app.

The problem with Magnolia is that it uses servlets such as jtl or jsp, where as phoneGap only accepts .html pages and does not render jtl or jsp pages.

So how would i go about in making only HTML5 pages?

Any ideas/suggestions/opinions will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is it that you want to make accessible on mobile with phone gap? Admin central or rendered web that was originally edited via Magnolia?
If the former, don't use phone gap, but instead clone Magnolia's source from git locally, change compile targets for widgets to allow compilation for iphone/android cell phones and you should have all you need to access admin interface on cell phone. On tablets it should already work w/o need to do anything.
If the latter, then what you want is to render whole web and capture html w/ curl or wget and give that to phone gap, tho I can't really imagine why/how that would be useful over phonegap-made app more then via browser directly.

HTH,
Jan